# Creating a function in R, using the inverse transformation method

Tags: r

[image: problem description]

I am confused about how to make a function for probabilities like these. I was taught the inverse method to be used for this problem as:

```r
X<-NULL
n<-number
uni<-runif(n,0,1)
X[uni<.1]=1
X[uni>.1 & uni<.3]=2
X[uni>.3 & uni<.6]=3
X[uni>.6 & uni<1]=4
length(which(X==1))/n
length(which(X==2))/n
length(which(X==3))/n
length(which(X==4))/n
```

I currently have:

```r
Prob<-function(n){ n<-as.integer(n)
uni<-runif(n,0,1)
X<-length(n)...??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In inverse transform sampling, you generate a random uniform between 0 and 1 and assign X to be the largest value x such that P(X<x)<=u.

```
myfunc=function(n) {
  X=c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    u=runif(1)
    if (u<=.1) {
      X[i]=1
    } else if (u<=.3) {
      X[i]=2
    } else if (u <= .6) {
      X[i]=3
    } else {
      X[i]=4
    }
  }
  return(X)
}

set.seed(39393)
X=myfunc(100)
mean(X)
sd(X)
```

output

```
> sd(X)
[1] 0.958745
> mean(X)
[1] 3.1
```

Comment: thank you so much, I had a question as to why the runif is 1? Is it because all the sums add up to 1

Comment: That means generate 1 runif random variable between 0 and 1